# Where is the Kubernetes YAML/JSON configuration files documentation?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hei,

I'm looking for the documentation for Kubernetes's configuration files. The ones used by kubectl (e.g. `kubectl create -f whatever.yaml`).

Basically, the Kubernetes equivalent of this [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) document.

I did search a lot but I didn't find much, or 404 links from old stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [official API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/) but a much more user-friendly way on the command line is the `explain` command, for example, I never remember what exactly goes into the spec of a pod, so I do:

```
$ kubectl explain Deployment.spec.template.spec
```

Comment: I guess the official generated API docs could have the information I'm looking for, but it's indeed not very user friendly and made for the REST api.

Thanks for the command line tip. Not very userfriendly as well, but it's a progress.